# UIAlertController does not display

Tags: ios, swift3

I have the following code in my Swift 3 project's main ViewController.swift file. When I call showAgreement(), then it executes without error, but no UI is displayed. How can I get UIAlertController to display?

My ViewController.swift file is defined as:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.showAgreement()
    }

    var alert: UIAlertController?

    func showAgreement() {

        alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert!.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

        alert!.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { action in
            switch action.style{
            case .default:
                print("default")

            case .cancel:
                print("cancel")

            case .destructive:
                print("destructive")
            }
        }))

        self.present(alert!, animated: true, completion: {

        })

    }

}
```

The console output says:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: Is there any message in the console?

Comment: Can you show where you're calling `showAgreement()`?

Comment: The console output says: Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x100e1f750> on <AwpiOSSampleApp.ViewController: 0x101001200> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: That means that ViewController is not the current VC

Comment: That's the ViewController that viewDidLoad() is fired on. How can it not be in the hierarchy or not being shown? I'm new to iOS development. My app shows my Main.storyboard and executes this ViewController.viewDidLoad() and all the buttons work. So I think this ViewController is working, other than not showing the UIAlert.

Comment: Can you try calling it from your viewDidAppear() function instead? You may be calling it too early in the VC lifecycle. Use override func viewDidAppear() { } instead.

Comment: That worked! Moving it to override func viewDidAppear worked. Thanks